# Using the width of parent element

Tags: html, css

How do i exactly use the parent's element width in css? I know this is a basic question but i'm using width: 50% on css expecting that the width would be 50% of the parent but instead it uses less than 50%.

In this example, i colored the parent as green so i could see the width and i was expecting each tab to be distributed along the green block.

Link to the example: https://jsfiddle.net/zfw81ojq/6/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BPO Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content" id="main-content" onclick="appendEl()">
        <div class="tab-selector">
            <div class="tablinks" onclick="openForm()"><h2>1st Tab</h2></div>
            <div class="tablinks" onclick="openForm()"><h2>2nd Tab</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 120px auto 120px;
    top: 30%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.content .tab-selector {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
}

.content .tab-selector .tablinks {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.content .tab-selector .tablinks h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: inline-block not inline

Comment: added 2 other duplicates related to issues you will face after using inline-block. The line-break due to white space and the padding (box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks :) the box-sizing advice was good -- Still i have another problem, the "inline-block" method makes both tabs to be on different lines, while i want them to be side by side.. I know you probably linked the answer but i can't figure out how to solve..
This is how it is now  https://jsfiddle.net/d1c2tz0j/19/

Comment: check all the duplicates

Comment: i found the answer, it was making every tab as float. However it wasn't in the duplicates. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: it's on the second duplicate

Comment: Oh okay i see it now, thanks :) I was looking only at the highest upvoted smh...
I can also use display:flex on the parent element instead ;) thanks for the lesson